# Would it be nice if i change the definition of local maximum or local minimum?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, maxima-minima

We know that the definition of local max value is "$f(a)$ is called $\textbf{local max value of f} $ if $f(a)\geq f(x)$ for all $x$ in some open interval containing $a$."

Would it be okay if I change the word "open" with "closed" i.e some closed interval?

Comment: Do you think it will make any difference?

Comment: Do so if you need to consider the endpoints.

Comment: Why does this question not meet guidelines? OP is asking clarification of a definition. For such a question, supplying the definition itself is context enough.

Answer (score 5):

Your proposal would not give an equivalent definition because the singleton $\{a\}$ is a "closed interval containing $a$".

Answer (score 4):

The other two answers point out that since $[a,a]$ is a closed interval, this definition makes **every** point into a local max or min.

This might feel like a technicality.  You might be more interested in a definition like this one:

> $f(a)$ is called a **local maximum** if $f(a) \geq f(x)$ for all $x$
> in some closed interval $[c,d]$ with $a \in [c,d]$ and $c < d$.

This also doesn't work.  Consider $f(x) = x$.  Then for every number $a$, $f(a)$ is a local max.  Use the interval $[a-1,a]$ to see this.

Now you might object that you don't want to allow $a$ to be one of the endpoints.  So your modified definition would be

> $f(a)$ is called a **local maximum** if $f(a) \geq f(x)$ for all $x$
> in some closed interval $[c,d]$ with $a \in [c,d]$ and $c < d$ and $a\neq c$ and $a \neq d$.

However this last definition is equivalent to the standard definition. If $a$ cannot be an endpoint, you might as well rule them out by considering an open interval instead.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the definition will make some changes. Consider the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ for all $x\in (0, \infty)$. As per our original definition, $f$ does not have any local maximum. But suppose we replace our open interval by closed interval then, at every point, $a \in (0,\infty)$, $f$ has a local maximum. I suggest you verify this claim!
We consider singleton sets as closed intervals, which will make every point local maximum point. You can refer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1565126/841303).

To understand the importance of considering the open intervals, I recommend you to go through the discussions in this question.
[Why are neighborhoods assumed to be open?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2813914/841303)